All separable solutions to linear parabolic PDE
I am trying to solve the following problem:
Consider the following linear parabolic PDE:
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} + ax^2\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} +bx\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} +cu = 0,\ u = u(x,t),\ a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$$
Find all separable solutions of the above equation of the form $u(x,t)=g(t)f(x)$.
Here is my working:
$$u_t=g'f,\,u_x=gf',\,u_{xx}=gf''\\
g'f+ax^2gf''+bgf'+cgf=0\\
-\dfrac{g'f}{g}=\dfrac{1}{f}\left(ax^2f''+bf'+cf\right)=\lambda$$
For $g(t):$ $$ g'=-\lambda g\Rightarrow \int\dfrac{1}{g}dg=-\lambda\int dt\\
\ln|y|=-\lambda t+\ln|A|,\ \therefore g(t)=Ae^{-\lambda t}\\$$
For $f(x):$
$$ax^2f''+bxf'+cf=\lambda f\\
f(x)=x^r\Rightarrow ar(r-1)x^r+brx^r+cxr-\lambda x^r=0\Rightarrow ar^2+(b-a)r+c-\lambda=0\\
r=\dfrac{-(b-a)\pm\sqrt{(b-a)^2-4a(c-\lambda)}}{2a}\\$$
Call the roots of the characteristic equation $r_1,\ r_2$.
$$\therefore f(x)=Bx^{r_1}+Cx^{r_2}\\$$
Finally, we have:
$$u(x,t)=g(t)f(x)=e^{-\lambda t}(C_1x^{r_1}+C_2x^{r_2})$$
Is this correct, or have I got the wrong idea?

What you did is correct but incomplete.
It is simpler to let $\lambda$  function of $r$ than $r$ function of $\lambda$ as you correctly found :
$$\lambda=ar^2+(b-a)r+c$$
An infinity of particular solutions are found :
$$u(x,t,r)=C_r x^r e^{-(ar^2+(b-a)r+c) t}$$
where $C_r$ are arbitrary constants.
The general solution is the linear combination of the particular solutions.
$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle\sum_{\forall r}\:C_r\,x^r e^{-(ar^2+(b-a)r+c) t}$$
